# entity framework dynamic schema load

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, sqlmetal

I'm working on a database schema that involves two static sales agency that have the same database model.

For example:
`dbo.User` becomes
`paris.User` and `toulouse.User`

Our project works with `Linq To SQL` and we use `sqlmetal` to generate two `map` files one for the **Paris** agency and the other for **Toulouse**.

With `active directory`, we are able to detect where the user come from and by that, we choose the map file corresponding to his agency.

My question is:

Is there a way to do the same in `Entity framework` ?

if not, what can i do ? and what's the best solution that i should follow, while using `Entity framework`.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple dbcontext in entity framework so depending on your agency you can use the different dbcontext.

Comment: can you give me a simple example please ?